# How do you properly chain promises in Javascript, and account for error handling?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am having some trouble understanding Javascript promises, specifically chaining them and passing errors up the chain.  In the following code:

```
function myPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('done')
      reject('resolved');
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function myOtherPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    myPromise().then(done => {
      resolve(done);
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log('In myOtherPromise, caught err: ', e);
      reject(e)
    });
  });
}

myOtherPromise().then(done => {
  console.log('done calling myOtherPromise: ', done);
}).catch(e => {
  console.log('caught err from myOtherPromise', err);
});
```

The output shows:

```
done
In myOtherPromise, caught err:  resolved
```

I don't understand why the following is not printed:

```
'caught err from myOtherPromise'
```

I feel like there is something fundamental I am not quite getting.  Why doesn't the rejection from `myOtherPromise` get passed to the final `catch` block?

Comment: because that function throws an error when trying to call console.log() `ReferenceError: err is not defined` ;)

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 4):

You catch the error into the `e` variable, but output the `err` variable (which is undefined and causes runtime error).

```
.catch(e => {
  console.log('caught err from myOtherPromise', err);
})
```

Should be:

```
.catch(e => {
  console.log('caught err from myOtherPromise', e);
})
```